# How to paginate the filtered results in django

Tags: python, django

```
views.py

def do_paginator(get_records_by_date,request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(get_records_by_date, 5)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return users


def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
        f_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
        print(f_date)
        to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
        t_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        print(t_date)
        new_records_check_box_status = request.POST.get("new_records", None)
        print(new_records_check_box_status)
        error_records_check_box_status = request.POST.get("error_records", None)
        print(error_records_check_box_status)
        drop_down_status = request.POST.get("field",None)
        print(drop_down_status)
        global get_records_by_date
        if new_records_check_box_status is None and error_records_check_box_status is None:
            get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(start_time__date__range=(f_date, t_date))
            get_records_by_date = check_drop_down_status(get_records_by_date,drop_down_status)
            get_records_by_date = do_paginator(get_records_by_date,request)
        elif new_records_check_box_status and error_records_check_box_status is None:
            get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(start_time__date__range=(f_date, t_date)).filter(new_records__gt=0)
            get_records_by_date = check_drop_down_status(get_records_by_date, drop_down_status)
            get_records_by_date = do_paginator(get_records_by_date, request)
        elif error_records_check_box_status and new_records_check_box_status is None:
            get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(start_time__date__range=(f_date, t_date)).filter(error_records__gt=0)
            get_records_by_date = check_drop_down_status(get_records_by_date, drop_down_status)
            get_records_by_date = do_paginator(get_records_by_date, request)
        else:
            get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(start_time__date__range=(f_date, t_date)).filter(Q(new_records__gt=0)|Q(error_records__gt=0))
            get_records_by_date = check_drop_down_status(get_records_by_date, drop_down_status)
            get_records_by_date = do_paginator(get_records_by_date,request)
        # print(get_records_by_date)
    else:
        roles =  Scrapper.objects.all()
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(roles, 5)
        try:
            users = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            users = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

   

 return render(request, "home.html",{"users": users})

return render(request, "home.html", {"users": get_records_by_date})

home.html



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
h2 {text-align: center;}
</style>

<h1>Facilgo Completed Jobs</h1>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <h2>Summary Details</h2>
  <table id="bootstrapdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>scrapper_id</th>
      <th>scrapper_jobs_log_id</th>
      <th>external_job_source_id</th>
      <th>start_time</th>
      <th>end_time</th>
      <th>scrapper_status</th>
      <th>processed_records</th>
      <th>new_records</th>
      <th>skipped_records</th>
      <th>error_records</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   {% for stud in users %}
    {% csrf_token %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{stud.scrapper_id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.scrapper_jobs_log_id}}</td>
      <td>{{stud.external_job_source_id}}</td>
      <td>{{stud.start_time}}</td>
        {% if  stud.end_time == None %}
          <td style="color:red">No result</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{stud.end_time}}</td>
        {% endif %}
        {% if  stud.scrapper_status == "1" %}
          <td>{{stud.scrapper_status}} --> Started</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{stud.scrapper_status}} --> Completed</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{stud.processed_records}}</td>
      <td>{{stud.new_records}}</td>
      <td>{{stud.skipped_records}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.error_records}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
  </table>
{% if users.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
   {% if users.has_previous %}
     <li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">«</a></li>
   {% else %}
     <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
   {% endif %}
   {% if user.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
   {% endif %}
   {% for i in users.paginator.page_range %}
     {% if users.number == i %}
    <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
    {% elif i > users.number|add:'-5' and i < users.number|add:'5' %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if users.has_next %}
     <li><a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">»</a></li>
   {% else %}
     <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
   {% endif %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I filter the datas the first page is getting the correct details. But when I click the next page its going to different datas. For the filtered element the datas should be obtained from the filtered query set. How to paginate according to the filtered datas. The second page is mismatched and returning to the original total datas.

```
Is there any solution to paginate the datas which has been filtered.
```

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the if else block, you can simply do as it is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function).

```
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(get_records_by_date, 5)
    users = paginator.get_page(page)
    return users
```

The django method already deals with input verification in the page GET, so you don't need to worry with the input you get.

Comment: For filtered elements the 1st page is showing the correct date when I click second page its showing different datas. But my 1st page should contain all datas

Comment: If you want only one page for showing all the data, then you don't need pagination. 
But if you still want to use pagination, you can do the following ``` paginator = Paginator(get_records_by_date, len(get_records_by_date)) ```

Comment: len(get_record_by_date) doesnt provide pagination. It will get all records. But I need to paginate records.